# Python nested for loop not printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to print a row of a csv file if an item is found in a csv.

1. CSV looks like this:

   - Avatar Name,Player Name,Player Number
   - LarchDew15,Emily,1
   - Pinerain2,Hannah,2
   - xOakenMaidx,Madison,3
   - Grandidel,Jacob,4
   - Gened123,Micheal,5
   - Tufty98,Matthew,6
   - silverstar,Ashley,7

```py
import csv



def player_number():

    # Opens CSV
    with open("battle_royale.csv") as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')  # extracts data from the file

        number = input("Member Number: ")

        # Looks to see if user number is in CSV file.
        found = False
        for column in readCSV:
            for x in column:
                if x == number:
                    found = True

        # If found prints out row
        if found:
            for row in readCSV:
                if number in row:
                    print(row)

    # Close input file
    csvfile.close()


def main():


    user = input("What do you want to do? ")

    playerNum = False

    # Find by Number
    if user == "b" or user == "B":
        playerNum = True
        if playerNum is True:
            player_number()


main()
```

Runs with no errors.

Comment: If it runs with no errors, then what's the problem? Also what's the point in checking whether `playerNum is True` the line after assigning `playerNum = True`?!

Comment: `found = any(x == number for column in readCSV for x in column)`.

Comment: Also, the file iterator doesn't reset after the loop that computes `found`; the next loop picks up where you left off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed quite a few redundant clauses, this should do:

```
import csv

def player_number():

    # Opens CSV
    with open("battle_royale.csv") as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')  # extracts data from the file

        number = input("Member Number: ")

        for row in readCSV:
            for value in row:
                if value == number:
                    print(row)



def main():
    user = input("What do you want to do? ")

    # Find by Number
    if user == "b" or user == "B":
        player_number()


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read a csv file using `csv.reader`, it splits the file into a list of rows, and each element in the row becomes a string. So in your comparison

`if x == number:`

You actually want to cast `number` as a string:

`if x == str(number)`